# Difference between breaking and non breaking space ascii characters

Tags: javascript, ascii

I have two identical strings in javascript with some spaces. When I printed the ascii values by using `str.charCodeAt(n)` it is showing the values as 32 and 160. I googled the values and it is showing me as breaking and non breaking spaces. So can anybody explain what is this behaviour.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the 2 strings you used?

Comment: Why is there a java tag?

Comment: Points to ponder: `charCodeAt` gives you a UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. The ASCII character set does not have a non-breaking space character (but that's okay, if you are using JavaScript, Java, .NET, HTML, XML, …, you're probably not using ASCII.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference between a normal (breaking) space and a non-breaking space is that text display and typesetting software should not insert an automatic line break in place of a non-breaking space.  (It is as if the non-breaking space joins the words before and after it into an unsplittable word.) By contrast, a regular space is treated as a possible place to break a line.

Having said that, the code `160` is actually outside of the range of regular (7-bit) ASCII.  The interpretation of `160` as a non-breaking space (or `NBSP`) character comes from the Latin1 (ISO8859-1) character set.  (In Extended ASCII, the code for the `NBSP` character is `255`!)

References:

- ["Non-breaking space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (Wikipedia)
- [ASCII and Extended ASCII code charts](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/non-breaking-space-no-break-space-ascii-code-255.html)
- ["The Latin-1 (ISO8859-1) Character Set"](http://casa.colorado.edu/~ajsh/iso8859-1.html)

Comment: •   Awesome!  When typing into a `textarea`, you can use `Alt`,`2`,`5`,`5` to force leading spaces before things like bullet points (`Alt`,`7` or `8` or `9`).  Otherwise browsers will not display leading nor trailing spaces.  However, some web apps implement `trim()` or similar techniques in order to remove or not display leading, trailing, duplicate, nor `\n` whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

A non-breaking space is a space that will not break into a new line.
Two words separated by a non-breaking space will stick together and not break into a new line.

Breaking spaces on the other hand will break.